# How can I get react-router to match against redirected url and show the appropriate component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, reactjs-flux, auth0

I'm using an external [authentication service](https://auth0.com/docs/client-platforms/react) in my app and after the user is authenticated, the service redirects the user to localhost:3045/#access_token=xxxx(with the idToken). How can I get react-router to match against redirected url and show the appropriate component?

The console error I'm getting after the user successfully authenticates through Auth0.

Warning: Location "/access_token=u3wkXAOg45VDhq6e&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NvdW5kY3RsLmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJnb29nbGUtb2F1dGgyfDEwNzc0OTM3NjI4ODQ4MDE2NjcyMCIsImF1ZCI6ImRhOG9MMGJaU2xqc2NLcjk0T3ExMVc3UDdBaVR2YjRMIiwiZXhwIjoxNDUxMjQzNTk3LCJpYXQiOjE0NTEyMDc1OTd9.-6dG3DDQ_UVKFDfxkJXu2hI7rQCnrGw6asmrcFJa_tk&token_type=Bearer&state=7cb2x0U4jxnAm1ft" did not match any routes

I've read the react-router path matching [documentation](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteMatching.md) but can't figure out how to make it match against access_token. The access_token / id_token will be different everytime the user authenticates.

Comment: For anyone stumbling upon this, see: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/2776